# what cast is missing in linq syntax?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

```
tblUserRole Permission = 
      (oCurrenUserPermission.GetPermission(Convert.ToString(Session["Navigation"])));
if (Permission.IsInsert == 1)
{
}

public IQueryable GetPermission(string sPageName)
{
   IQueryable query;
   #region MyRegion
   query = from r in this.Context.tblUserRoles
              join p in this.Context.tblPageInfos on r.PageID equals p.PageID
             where r.Record_Status == 2 && p.PageName == sPageName
           select r;
   return query;
  #endregion
 }
```

Above syntax show the bellow error:

**Error 1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'AkijBeverage.ServiceObject.tblUserRole'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)    E:\Project-Akij\09-July-2010\AkijBeverage\AkijBeverage\SecurityUserControls\UCUserRole.ascx.cs  63  43  AkijBeverage**

**How to solve this ?**

Comment: no it's return one row value.Instead of r.IsInsert i can use r

Comment: I would strongly suggest you work on your naming standards.  See below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, that query is just not compatible with `tblUserRole`.

It's going to return a `IEnumereable<bool>` instead of a tblUserRole.
The real problem is that you are selecting the `IsInsert` in two different spots:  In the query, and again in the `if()`

The easiest way would be just return the full tblUserRole object:

```
return (from r in this.Context.tblUserRoles 
                join p in this.Context.tblPageInfos on r.PageID equals p.PageID 
                where r.Record_Status == 2 && p.PageName == sPageName 
                select r).SingleOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently you're returning a query - not a single item. What do you *want* to return?

Here's one option, for example:

```
public tblUserRole GetPermission(string sPageName)
{
    return (from r in this.Context.tblUserRoles
            join p in this.Context.tblPageInfos on r.PageID equals p.PageID
            where r.Record_Status == 2 && p.PageName == sPageName
            select r).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

This will return the first matching role, or `null` if there aren't any.

If you *do* want to return a query, it would be better as a strongly typed `IQueryable<T>`:

```
public IQueryable<tblUserRole> GetPermissions(string sPageName)
{
    return from r in this.Context.tblUserRoles
           join p in this.Context.tblPageInfos on r.PageID equals p.PageID
           where r.Record_Status == 2 && p.PageName == sPageName
           select r;
}
```

Then you'd need to change your calling code to something like this:

```
tblUserRole Permission 
   oCurrenUserPermission.GetPermissions(Convert.ToString(Session["Navigation"]))
                        .FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is you have an IQueryable and are attempting to assign to a "Type" without a cast.

Either change your method to:

```
  public IQueryable<tblUserRole > GetPermission(string sPageName)
```

and then do  (First/FirstOrDefault/Single/etc..)

```
 oCurrenUserPermission.GetPermission(...).FirstOrDefault();
```

Or cast it and cross your fingers and select one.

```
   (tblUserRole)oCurrenUserPermission.GetPermission(...).FirstOrDefault();
```

**Side Note**

I would suggest you work on naming your code in a more friendly maner.  No need to prepend the "type" at the beginning.  For example a possible better way to name everything:

```
 string navigationValue = Convert.ToString(Session["Navigation"]);

 UserRole permission = 
  currentUserPermission.GetPermission(navigationValue ).FirstOrDefault();

 //If this isn't a boolean i would consider using one
 if (permission.IsInsert == 1)
 {
 }

 public IQueryable<UserRole> GetPermission(string sPageName)
 {

    #region MyRegion
    var query = from r in this.Context.UserRoles
                    join p in this.Context.PageInformation on r.PageID equals p.PageID
                where r.Record_Status == 2 && p.PageName == sPageName
                select r;
   return query;
   #endregion
 }
```